# I'm building a search input with suggestions and i'm returning blank rows from my DB

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, search

[image: search page]

[image: mysql table and DB]

building a search that auto suggests..

My queries suggestions are showing up blank and I'm not sure why...

html form:

```
![<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Meta -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>PHP Builds Suggestions</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <!-- Load CSS -->
    <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Load Fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:regular,bold" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Load jQuery library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Load custom js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/custom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">

        <!-- Main Title -->
        <div class="icon"></div>
        <h1 class="title">PHP Builds taste suggestions</h1>
        <h5 class="title">PHP Builds your taste buds</h5>

        <!-- Main Input -->
        <input type="text" id="search" autocomplete="off">

        <!-- Show Results -->
        <h4 id="results-text">Showing results for: <b id="search-string">Array</b></h4>
        <ul id="results"></ul>


    </div>

</body>
</html>][3]


// Credentials
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "builds";
$dbuser = "xxxxxxx";
$dbpass = "xxxxxxx";

//  Connection
global $tutorial_db;

$tutorial_db = new mysqli();
$tutorial_db->connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
$tutorial_db->set_charset("utf8");

//  Check Connection
if ($tutorial_db->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $tutorial_db->connect_error);
    exit();
}

/************************************************
    Search Functionality
************************************************/

// Define Output HTML Formating
$html = '';
$html .= '<li class="result">';
$html .= '<a target="_blank" href="urlString">';
$html .= '<h3>nameString</h3>';
$html .= '<h4>functionString</h4>';
$html .= '</a>';
$html .= '</li>';

// Get Search
$search_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", " ", $_POST['query']);
$search_string = $tutorial_db->real_escape_string($search_string);

// Check Length More Than One Character
if (strlen($search_string) >= 1 && $search_string !== ' ') {
    // Build Query
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM intelli WHERE Rest LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%" OR dish LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%"';

    // Do Search
    $result = $tutorial_db->query($query);
    while($results = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $result_array[] = $results;
    }

    // Check If We Have Results
    if (isset($result_array)) {
        foreach ($result_array as $result) {

            // Format Output Strings And Hightlight Matches
            $display_function = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['function']);
            $display_name = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['name']);
            $display_url = 'http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern='.urlencode($result['function']).'&lang=en';

            // Insert Name
            $output = str_replace('nameString', $display_name, $html);

            // Insert Function
            $output = str_replace('functionString', $display_function, $output);

            // Insert URL
            $output = str_replace('urlString', $display_url, $output);

            // Output
            echo($output);
        }
    }else{

        // Format No Results Output
        $output = str_replace('urlString', 'javascript:void(0);', $html);
        $output = str_replace('nameString', '<b>No Results Found.</b>', $output);
        $output = str_replace('functionString', 'Sorry :(', $output);

        // Output
        echo($output);
    }
}
```

If anyone can lend a hand as to why this might be happening...Thanks in advance.

Comment: in you php response you have <li class="result"><a target="_blank" href="http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=&lang=en"><h3></h3><h4></h4></a></li> and no data. So start by refactoring your php code.

Comment: My guess would be `while($results = $result->fetch_array()) {` should be `while($results = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {`

Comment: Thanks guys, i fixed it, when i noticed the URL i relized i hadn't changed my field names.